# Python: SecurePDF decryption ( PyPDF2 )

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I am looking for a python based way to decrypt secure pdfs.

For me its not possible to use installation required libs like `qpdf`.

Otherwise any hints how i could start to write a method to decrypt by myself in python ?

Current way is not supported anymore:

```
import PyPDF2

ENCRYPTED_FILE_PATH = 'encrypted1.pdf'

with open(ENCRYPTED_FILE_PATH, mode='rb') as f:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
    if reader.isEncrypted:
        reader.decrypt('master')
        print(f"Number of page: {reader.getNumPages()}")
```

> NotImplementedError: only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported

Python: 3.5.2
OS: Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPDF2 has received a lot of updates in 2022, including encryption support.

PyPDF2 was also deprecated in favor of pypdf (I'm the maintainer of both projects).

Upgrade your code, use `pypdf` and you should be good :-)